# Surface area of a sphere by cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was resolving a problem of electromagnetism that I needed relating the 1/4 surface area of sphere with electrical field. Well, using spherical coordinates is very easy to do that.

Take a look:

[image]

\begin{align}
d\overline{E}&=d\overline{E}_r+d\overline{E}_z \\
 & = dE\;(cos\theta\;\hat{a}_z+sin\theta\;\hat{a}_r) \\
 \end{align}
\begin{align}
E=\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{{\pi}/{2}}\frac{\rho_sR^2sin\theta}{4\pi\varepsilon_sR^2}(cos\theta\;\hat{a}_z+sin\theta\;\hat{a}_r) \\
 \end{align}

Note that: I need to transform those vectors $\hat{a}_z$ and $\hat{a}_r$ to spherical coordinates. It is too easy because: $\hat{a}_z = \hat{a}_R.cos\theta$ and $\hat{a}_r = \hat{a}_R.sin\theta$, since $\hat{a}_R$ is one of the spherical coordinates unit vector.

But I'd like to know when I transform to cylindrical coordinates what these variables **NOT** change? $r$, $\phi$ or $z$?

How would that equation after transform this integral by another system coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a language barrier here, but what I take "what these variables NOT change?" to mean: which of these variables doesn't change under the transform from spherical to cylindrical co-ordinates: the $ r $ and $ \phi $ variables remain unchanged and the $ \theta $ variable transforms as

$ \theta = cos^{-1} ( \frac{z}{r} ) $

where $ z $ is the new co-ordinate (the height on the cylinder).

You transform the integral by substituting this in place of $ \theta $ and inserting a $ \dfrac{d \theta}{dz} dz $ term in the integral.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English text. I write very quickly and I mess up several means, including the correct integral. The integral is $\int_{\phi=0}^\pi \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}[\text{whatever}]R.d\theta\,R\sin\theta d\phi$. How would it look like? Like this: $\int_{\phi=0}^\pi \int_{\theta=0}^{cos^{-1}(\frac{z}{r})}[\text{whatever}]dz\, rd\phi$?